laravel to use tailwind classes on all my pages
It is a small laravell app, I modified the tailwind.config.js file like this:
export default {
    darkMode: 'class',="dark">


and the app.blade.php file like this:
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}" class="dark">

It only works on the welcome page but not on the login, register pages. It goes back to the light mode.
why is that?
I want all my pages using the dark tailwind css class

Are you sure the login/register pages extend app.blade.php?

You usually have a different layout for the login/register pages. It's usually called guest.blade.php. Make sure to also add the class in that layout.
